# Как я могу зафиксировать футер?

Tags: html, css

Перепробовал уже много способов, но всё никак не получается.

```css
@Charset "UTF-8"; 
    * {   
     margin: 0;
     outline: none; 
    } 
    
    body, html {height: 100%}
    
    body { 
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%; 
     background-color: #FAEEDD; 
     color: black;
     font-size: 1em;
     font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif; 
    } 
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;
    }
    
    img {
     width: 25%;
     height: 25%;
     width: auto/9;
     margin-left: 260px;
    }
    
    .left {float: left};
    /* в img максимально 100% изоброжение будет подстраиватся под блок и не вылезать из него и auto/9 это для эксплоера браузера*/
    
    header, footer { 
     width: 98%; 
     min-height: 50px; 
     float: left;
     background-color: white;
    } 
    
    header { 
     border-bottom: 3px solid grey; 
     padding: 1%;
     background-color: white;
    } 
    
    aside {
     width: 400px;
     height:605px;
     max-width: 100%;
     border: 3px solid grey;
     border-top: 0px; 
     font-size: 25px;
     background-color: white;
     padding-top: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 35px;
    }
    
    hr {
     display: block;
     border: 0;
     height: 1px;
     border-top: 2px solid grey;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    center {
     width: 1000px;
     height: 500px;
     max-width: 100%;
     border: 0px solid grey;
     background-color: #FAEEDD;
     font-size: 35px;
     font-weight: bold;
     position: absolute; top: 260px; left: 500px; 
    }
    
    .colortext {color: red};
    /* стили для футера*/
    
    footer { 
     border-top: 3px solid grey; 
     margin-top: 10px; 
     padding: 1%;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .content:after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
    }
    .content:after, footer {
     height: 10px;
    }
    .content {
     min-height: 77%;
     margin-bottom: -10px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <a href="englishfan.html" title="Homepage" id="logo"><img src="img/london1.jpg" alt="LearningEnglish" title="LearningEnglish" /></a>
</header>

<aside>
  <div id="menuhrefs"></div><pre><a href="presentsimple.html"> Present simple</a>
  <hr /><a href="pastsimple.html"> Past simple</a>
  <hr /><a href="presentcontinuous.html"> Present continuous</a>
  <hr /><a href="pastcontinuous.html"> Past continuous</a>
  <hr /><a href="presentperfect.html"> Present perfect</a>
  <hr /><a href="pastperfect.html"> Past perfect</a>
  <hr /><a href="presentperfectcontinuous.html"> Present perfect continuous</a>
  <hr /><a href="cancould.html"> Can, could</a>
  <hr /><a href="willwould.html"> Will, would</a>
  <hr /><a href="reading.html"> Reading</a></pre>
</aside>

<center>
  On this site you can find:<br /><br />
  <span class="colortext">Basic grammar English rules</span> (you can learn the rules that are easy to understand and easy to learn).<br /><br />
  <span class="colortext">Exercises in English</span> (you can do any exercises for present, past and future).<br /><br />
  <span class="colortext">Tests reading</span> (if you want to do tests on READING you don't need pay for it, it’s all for free).<br /><br />
</center>

<div class="content"></div>
<footer>
  <span class="left">Privacy policy &copy; 2018</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: position: fixed; - зафиксирует ваш футер, див, спан, что хотите, то и зафиксирует.

Comment: что значит зафиксировать? прижать к низу страницы?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-itm {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-itm">1</div>
  <div class="flex-itm">1</div>
  <div class="flex-itm">1</div>
  <div class="flex-itm">1</div>
  <div class="flex-itm">1</div>
  <div class="flex-itm">1</div>
</div>
```

Через флексы можно попробовать

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```css
.footer{
 margin:-550px;
 height:550px;
}

.clr {
 clear:both;
 height:550px
}
```

```html
<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```